# View that pulls similar data from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, view

Lets say I have a table called Players and another table called Coaches.

Each table has columns FirstName, LastName, UserID, Address.

There is currently a view called PeopleView which is a simple select statement.

```
    select FirstName, LastName, UserID from Players;
```

I now want PeopleView to also return the same data from the Coaches table.

```
    select FirstName, LastName, UserID from Coaches;
```

So now when this view is executed it will show all players and coaches in the database even though you will not know which record is a coach or player.

Thanks and I am hoping this is easy for sql experts.

Comment: UNION ALL your queries.

Comment: Why is the first and last name in those tables? Shouldn't it be in the user table the user ID refers to? Do the people change their names when they are player or coach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But, you *can* know who is who by adding yet another *column*:

```
select 'Player' what, FirstName, LastName, UserID from Players
union all
select 'Coach'  what, FirstName, LastName, UserID from Coaches
```